# Mechanics collision between two point masses

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider a one-dimensional force ﬁeld given by the formula
$$F(x, m) = −kmx, k > 0, x ∈ (−∞, ∞)$$
that acts on a point mass $P$ of mass $m$ located at position $x$.

Consider two point masses $P_1$ and $P_2$ with $m_1=m_2=m$, and with initial conditions
$x_1(0) = l > 0, x_2(0) = 2l > 0$ and  $\dot{x}_1(0) = \dot{x}_2(0) = 0 $

Show that the ﬁrst collision of $P_2$ with $P_1$ occurs at $x = 0$. Compute the time
$T_1$ when this collision occurs.

This question is basically one part of a couple parts to a larger question. I have already obtained the function for the trajectory which is $$x(t)=a\sin(t\sqrt{k}+\frac \pi 2)$$

Now where this looks simple, I'm just having a bit of issue working it out because I can't see how $P_1$ and $P_2$ are going to differ at all really, and just generally confused where to start to get the $T_1$ I'm pretty sure I'm just overlooking this while it shouldn't be too difficult but could anyone lend a hand?

Comment: If you know that $$x(t)=a\sin\left(t\sqrt{k}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$ and that $t=T_{1}$ is the time when $x(t)=0$, then you can solve for $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Newton's second law we have
$$
\begin{cases}
m_1\ddot{x}_1=-km_1x_1\\
m_2\ddot{x}_2=-km_2x_2
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
\ddot{x}_1=-kx_1\\
\ddot{x}_2=-kx_2
\end{cases}.
$$
Solving these two differential equations we get:
$$
x_1(t)=A_1\cos(\sqrt{k}t+\varphi_1),\quad x_2(t)=A_2\cos(\sqrt{k}t+\varphi_2),
$$
where $A_1,A_2$ are positive real constants, and $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in [0,2\pi)$.

Using the initial conditions we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
A_1\cos\varphi_1=l\\
-\sqrt{k}A_1\sin\varphi_1=0\\
A_2\cos\varphi_2=2l\\
-\sqrt{k}A_2\sin\varphi_2=0
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
(\varphi_1,A_1)=(0,l)\\
(\varphi_2,A_2)=(0,2l)
\end{cases}.
$$
Hence
$$
x_1(t)=l\cos(\sqrt{k}t),\quad x_1(t)=2l\cos(\sqrt{k}t).
$$
There is a collision at any time $t$ such that
$$
x_1(t)=x_2(t),
$$
i.e. when
$$
\cos(\sqrt{k}t)=0.
$$
Thus these collisions occur at any
$$
t_n=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{k}}+\frac{2n\pi}{\sqrt{k}}, \quad n=0,1,2,\ldots.
$$
Thus, the first collision occurs at 
$$
T_1=\min_nt_n=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{k}}.
$$
The corresponding position where the first collision occurs is:
$$
x_1(T_1)=x_2(T_1)=l\cos\frac\pi2=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The $a$ in your equation is the position of the mass at $t=0$.  Your masses $P_1$ and $P_2$ therefore have different values of $a$, so write $x_1(t)=\dots, x_2(t)=\dots$.  A collision happens when $x_1(t)=x_2(t)$, so solve that equation for the minimum positive $t$, then plug that in to find $x_1=x_2=0$

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem very easily using the [phase space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) approach. Note that the initial point of the two particles in the phase space $(v,x)$ are $(0,l),\ (0,2l)$ respectively. Under the above mentioned force field the phase trajectory will be ellipse with both of them having the same eccentricity with different major axis lengths ($l,\ 2l$ respectively). Then, it is evident that they will have the same $x$ coordinate for the first time in the phase space when $x=0$ and the time required to do that is $1/4$ th of their period of motion which means that the first time to collision is $$T=(2\pi/\sqrt{k})/4=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{k}}$$